# Android Spannabe Emoji loads slow in GridView and TextView

Tags: android, gridview, emoji, emoticons, spannablestring

I am making a little chat in my Android app and I am using emojis (emoticons) that displays in EditText and TextView with SpannableString.

For that I made a class (code is below). Also I made a gridview which loads all the emojis. The problem is that all works is very slow (because I have 500 emojis) It takes a lot to load and display the emojis. Below is the code I'm using.

I am looking for a better algorithm to replace the String with an emoji or another way load the emojis faster.

```
public class EmoticonHandler {

private static final Map<String, Integer> emoticons = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private static void addPattern(Map<String, Integer> map, String smile,
        int resource) {
    map.put(smile, resource);
}

// Add the items to the HasMap
static {

    // Smileys
    addPattern(emoticons, "#ce001#", R.drawable._ce001_);
    addPattern(emoticons, "#ce002#", R.drawable._ce002_);
    addPattern(emoticons, "#ce003#", R.drawable._ce003_);
    addPattern(emoticons, "#ce004#", R.drawable._ce004_);
     // Here comes the other 500 emojis

}

// Get image for each text smiles
public static void getSmiledText(Context context, Spannable span, int size) {

    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < span.length(); index++) {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {
            int length = entry.getKey().length();
            if (index + length > span.length())
                continue;
            if (span.subSequence(index, index + length).toString()
                    .equals(entry.getKey())) {

                span.setSpan(new EmoticonSpan(context, entry.getValue(),
                        size), index, index + length,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                index += length - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}}
```

Here is the code for the EmoticonSpan

```
public class EmoticonSpan extends DynamicDrawableSpan {

private Context context;
private int resourceID;
private int size;
private Drawable drawable;

public EmoticonSpan(Context context, int resourceID, int size) {
    super();

    this.context = context;
    this.resourceID = resourceID;
    this.size = size;

}

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable() {

    if (drawable == null) {
        try {
            drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceID);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Swallow
        }
    }
    return drawable;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android guide recommendation to display grid view images smoothly and off your main up thread. 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html#gridview

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Ended up using Emoji maps. Just cram Emojis on a (single) image of no more than 2048X2048 (the biggest Android can handle), and show that as the input grid. Then calculate the X/Y position and find out which Emoji was pointed by the user.

Just remember to take into consideration different device sizes (mdpi ... xxxdpi), and calculate position with correct scroll, and resize offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is good code for you :

```
public class EmojiKeyboard {

    private static final String TAG = "EmojiKeyboard";
    private static final String PREF_KEY_HEIGHT_KB = "EmojiKbHeight";

    private Context context;
    private int screenHeight = -1;
    private int emojiKbHeight = -1;
    private PopupWindow emojiKeyboardPopup;
    private View view;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public EmojiKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            this.context = context;
            this.view = view;
            preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            //Restore EmojiKeyboard Height
            emojiKbHeight = preferences.getInt(PREF_KEY_HEIGHT_KB, -1);

            //TODO support less then 11 API, and not perfect resizing when switched the keyboard
            view.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                    /*
                    * Get root view height
                    * */
                    screenHeight = screenHeight == -1 && bottom > oldBottom
                            ? bottom
                            : screenHeight;

                    /*
                    * Calculate soft keyboard height
                    * */
                    int dHeight = oldBottom - bottom;
                    boolean validHeight = emojiKbHeight == -1 && dHeight > 80 && bottom != oldBottom;

                    /*
                    * Сheck twice because the keyboard may have been switched
                    * */
                    emojiKbHeight = validHeight
                            ? dHeight : emojiKbHeight != (dHeight) && dHeight > 0
                            ? dHeight
                            : emojiKbHeight;

                    /*
                    * Store emoji keyboard height into SharedPreferences
                    * */
                    preferences.edit().putInt(PREF_KEY_HEIGHT_KB, emojiKbHeight).commit();

                    /*
                    * If layout returned to a standard height then dismissing keyboard (OnBackPressed)
                    * */
                    if (screenHeight == bottom) {
                        dismissEmojiKeyboard();
                    }

                    /*
                    * Resize emoji on the go when a user switches between keyboards
                    * */
                    resizeEmoji();
                }
            });
        }
    }


    public void showEmoji() {
        if (emojiKeyboardPopup == null) {
            createEmojiKeyboard();
        }
        if (!isShowed()) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    emojiKeyboardPopup.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                    resizeEmoji();
                }
            }, 10L);

        } else {
            dismissEmojiKeyboard();
        }
    }

    public void createEmojiKeyboard() {
        EmojiView emojiKeyboard = new EmojiView(context, EmojiView.EMOJI_DARK_STYLE, new EmojiView.onEmojiClickListener() {
            public void onBackspace() {
                if (((Activity) context).getWindow().getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText) {
                    ((Activity) context).getWindow().getCurrentFocus().dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 67));
                }
            }

            public void onEmojiSelected(Emojicon emojicon) {
                if (((Activity) context).getWindow().getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText) {
                    EmojiView.input((EditText) ((Activity) context).getWindow().getCurrentFocus(), emojicon);
                }
            }
        });
        emojiKeyboardPopup = new PopupWindow(emojiKeyboard);
        emojiKeyboardPopup.setHeight(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(setEmojiKeyboardHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        emojiKeyboardPopup.setWidth(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getDisplayDimensions(context).x, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        emojiKeyboardPopup.setAnimationStyle(0);
    }

    public void dismissEmojiKeyboard() {
        if (isShowed()) {
            emojiKeyboardPopup.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public boolean isShowed() {
        return emojiKeyboardPopup != null && emojiKeyboardPopup.isShowing();
    }

    /*
    * Emoji set up size
    * */
    public void resizeEmoji() {
        if (isShowed()) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) emojiKeyboardPopup.getContentView().getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = setEmojiKeyboardHeight();
            wm.updateViewLayout(emojiKeyboardPopup.getContentView(), layoutParams);
        }
    }

    public int setEmojiKeyboardHeight() {
        return emojiKbHeight == -1 && emojiKbHeight != screenHeight && emojiKbHeight < 80
                ? (getDisplayDimensions(context).y / 2)
                : emojiKbHeight;
    }

    public Point getDisplayDimensions(Context context) {
        Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager w = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        } else {
            Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
            size.x = d.getWidth();
            size.y = d.getHeight();
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```